# Can I claim a capital loss on property I gifted?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, capital-loss, connecticut

I had some cryptocurrency with an unrealized capital loss that I gave to someone as a gift.

My adjusted cost basis just before I made the gift was $4,000.

The fair market value (FMV) of the cryptocurrency at the time I made the gift was $1,500.

Under United States federal and Connecticut state tax law, may I claim a capital loss, and if so, how much?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you cannot, because you didn't lose any money. You gifted it away. The donee can claim capital loss based on the FMV or gain based on your cost basis (see [the rules on the IRS site](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/capital-gains-losses-and-sale-of-home/property-basis-sale-of-home-etc/property-basis-sale-of-home-etc)).

Comment: Thank you, but how do you know I didn't realize my unrealized capital loss on the date that I made the gift?

Comment: You only realize gains or losses on a sale or exchange, not on a gift.  
You can't just "decide" to realize a loss.  See https://www.irs.gov/publications/p544#en_US_2021_publink100072605

Comment: Had you sold the cryptocurrency and then gifted the money, then you'd get to realize the loss.  Since you didn't - you don't.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no, not for losses it doesn't. The difference between FMV and the cost basis doesn't provide any tax benefit to the beneficiary.